# How can you display your profile (flair) on a free wordpress blog?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

Hi,

I've got a little blog that I'm trying to build up, I want to include my stack overflow profiles on a side bar.

I can see various different methods for doing this under the "got flair" link on my SO account

However, with free wordpress accounts (such as myblog.wordpress.com), javascript is disabled, therefore I have to have the reputation hardcoded in standard HTML.

Surely there must be an alternative method? Possibly reference an image that gets updated periodically?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is an app that does this using the API.  It creates images instead of whatever the flair uses.

It's called [Stack Image](https://stackapps.com/questions/847/stackimage-generating-images-of-questions-and-users).

[Example http://stackimage.quickmediasolutions.com/flair.php?id=2598&site=stackoverflow&background=eeeeee&border=ffffff&text=555555&title=5555ff&font1=sans&font2=sansbold](http://stackimage.quickmediasolutions.com/flair.php?id=2598&site=stackoverflow&background=eeeeee&border=ffffff&text=555555&title=5555ff&font1=sans&font2=sansbold)

Comment: +1 ...and that's not just because I wrote it :)

Comment: @George, i knew I could count on a vote from you!